# Applying a function to a list and outputting results

Tags: r

I've got a big database which I've split up by year and created at train and test for each respective year

```
#split the dataset into a list of datasets 
Y <- split(dat_all, dat_all$year)
#create a train and test dataset for all years
#takes Y is inp
create_sets <- function(x){
    train_set <- sample(2, nrow(x), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3)) 
    train <- x[train_set == 1, ]
    test <- x[train_set == 2, ]
    assign('x', list(train = train, test = test))
}
Ylist <- lapply(Y, create_sets)
```

To call each item out you use Ylist$'2016'$train

I've made an accuracy ratio function which I can run each list through individually but I am looking for a way to do it all in one to save massive amounts of code (theres 16 years of data)

Below is how I currently create an accuracy ratio for one year

```
val_train<-Ylist$'2016'$train
val_train$pred<-predict(modf,newdata=Ylist$'2016'$train)
val_train$probs<-exp(val_train$pred)/(1+exp(val_train$pred))
x<-data.frame(rcorr.cens(val_train$probs, val_train$default_flag))
train_AR<-x[2,1]
train_AR

modfull <-ModFit(test)
val_test<-test
val_test$pred<-predict(modf,newdata=test)
val_test$probs<-exp(val_test$pred)/(1+exp(val_test$pred))
x<-data.frame(rcorr.cens(val_test$probs, val_test$default_flag))
test_AR<-x[2,1]
test_AR

AR_Logistic1<-c(train_AR,test_AR,)
AR_Logistic2<-c(train_AR,test_AR) #just in to see if table works
AccuracyRatio<-rbind(AR_Logistic1,AR_Logistic2)
colnames(AccuracyRatio)<-c("Train","Test","All")
AccuracyRatio
```

Just to clarify I'm trying to run through my whole list through my accuracy ratio and then output the AR for each year for its train and test.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `lapply` and wrapping the AR calculations in a function you can summarise the output as below. 
Without sample data, I could not test it but let us know if you face any errors.

```
fn_Calc_AR <- function(yearDat = listInput)  {

#yearDat <== Ylist$'2016'

trainDat <- yearDat$train
testDat <- yearDat$test

val_train<- trainDat
val_train$pred<-predict(modf,newdata= trainDat)
val_train$probs<-exp(val_train$pred)/(1+exp(val_train$pred))
x<-data.frame(rcorr.cens(val_train$probs, val_train$default_flag))
train_AR<-x[2,1]
#train_AR

modfull <-ModFit(testDat)
val_test<-testDat
val_test$pred<-predict(modf,newdata=testDat)
val_test$probs<-exp(val_test$pred)/(1+exp(val_test$pred))
x<-data.frame(rcorr.cens(val_test$probs, val_test$default_flag))
test_AR<-x[2,1]
#test_AR

AR_Logistic1<-c(train_AR,test_AR)   # removed extraneous comma, previous input c(train_AR,test_AR,)
AR_Logistic2<-c(train_AR,test_AR)   #just in to see if table works
AccuracyRatio<-rbind(AR_Logistic1,AR_Logistic2)
colnames(AccuracyRatio)<-c("Train","Test","All")

#confirm yearName is being created 
try(yearName <- head(names(x),1)) #retain only year

if(length(yearName) > 0L) {
 AR_DF <- data.frame(yearName = yearName , AccuracyRatio,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}else{
 AR_DF <- AccuracyRatio
}

return(AR_DF)

}
```

**Summarise Output:**

```
AR_Summary = do.call(rbind,lapply(Ylist,fn_Calc_AR))
```

**Aggregate Dataset:**

```
aggregateTrain  = do.call(rbind,lapply(Ylist,function(x) x$train))
aggregateTest  = do.call(rbind,lapply(Ylist,function(x) x$test))

aggregateList = list(train = aggregateTrain,test = aggregateTest)

AR_AggregateSummary = do.call(rbind,lapply(aggregateList,function(x) fn_Calc_AR(x) ))
```

Comment: Hi, this all works fine so I've marked it as correct. However, a few little questions. In the table the names of each year is called by using x. This outputs "2008 rcorr.cens.val_train_test.probs..val_train_test.default_flag." is there a way to just have the year?

Comment: One more thing then Im done. I'm also trying to run the accuracy ratio on the whole year set eg test + train. Tried adding this in trainDat <- yearDat$train
testDat <- yearDat$test
trainDat_testDat <-yearDat
 and then adding in another section for trainDat_testDat but to no success. Any ideas on how I could do this? Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: I know I've marked it as correct which it is but I would really appreciate some extra help

Comment: I have updated the answer could you try now but with no reproducible data I cannot be sure if this works perfectly,